# alpinelinux 3.12 missing man package?

Tags: alpine-linux, manpage, alpine-package-keeper

I'm trying to get manpages working on alpinelinux 3.12, used latest 3.12 version and:

```
# apk add man
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  man (missing):
    required by: world[man]
```

Weird? apk add man-pages works perfectly. I've enabled all repos (community, edge, etc) apk update and still can't find man?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the problem they changed package name from **man to mandoc**. apk add man doesn't work anymore, it's:
`# apk add mandoc`
 in 3.12

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you, solved the problem for me.